# Android package security

Tags: android, security, package

in Android's security and permissions guide it states:

> At install time, Android gives each package a distinct Linux user ID. The identity remains constant for the duration of the package's life on that device. On a different device, the same package may have a different UID; what matters is that each package has a distinct UID on a given device.

What I'm wondering is: by "**package**" are they referring to an application that is installed on a device, or to **Java's package** names in a project?  Can someone explain?

Thanks,
Igor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It refers to the unique android package name defined in [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package), not the Java package.

Answer (score 1):

One of the java package name will have to be mentioned in androidmain.xml as the packagename for android system. So essentially they mean the package that is gonna be on device. Obviously it means Java package name as well .